# Convert hours into days:Hours format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Table 
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    WorkHours int
)
```

This is my table which stores working hours as integer. My requirement is to display work hours in `DD:HH` format. How is it possible?

Comment: Never in my life have I seen a `days:hours` format. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: from where DD should be reference?

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? You have hours, e.g. 33. That makes 1 day and 9 hours (33 = 24 + 9). So this is just math and then a string operation to display this as 'dd:hh'.

Answer (score 2):

To get it DD:HH format, you'll need to do some math as well as some 00 padding (or you get D:H) format:

```
select RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WorkHours / 24), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WorkHours% 24), 2)
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

- Integer division in SQL-Server is `int1 / int2`.
- Modulo in SQL-Server is `int1 % int2`.
- The function for formatting numbers in SQL-Server is `FORMAT`.
- The string concatenation operator in SQL-Server is the non-standard `+`.

The query:

```
select format(workhours / 24, '00') + ':' + format(workhours % 24, '00')
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with Calcs as
(
select id, floor(WorkHours/24) as DDField, (WorkHours/24)-floor(WorkHours/24) as HHField
from MyTable
)
select id, DDField + ':' + HHField
from Calcs
```

Comment: You could use `WorkHours%24` instead of `(WorkHours/24)-floor(WorkHours/24)`

Comment: Also, WorkHours is an `INT`, so no need for `FLOOR` either

Comment: @Lamak I am not flooring the field, I am flooring the calc

Comment: The calculation is using ints, so the result will be an int. It's an integer division